# Secure Grails Rest Api with Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: security, rest, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Can I use spring-security-rest as a replacement of Oauth?. My app has server side part and java script client side part where I found that spring-security-rest plugin fits most. But I want to be able to authenticate other apps who want to consume my service (I want to be something like Oauth provider). Does spring-security-rest plugin support this? or should I use another plugin?

Comment: *The Spring Security REST Grails plugin allows you to use Spring Security for a stateless, token-based, RESTful authentication.* So yes, you can. [Reading through the fine manual](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/introduction.html) will help understand how the plugin can also work as a delegator to other OAuth providers.

Comment: Actually what I want is to let my application be something like OAuth provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is not a fully OAuth provider. Or said in OAuth terminology, is not a full Authorisation Server.

In that case I recommend you [Spring Security OAuth 2 Provider Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for a simplistic token based **authentication** for your service, you could leverage the `spring security rest plugin` and tweak it a little bit based on your need without having to implement the full blown Spring `Security OAuth2 Provider plugin`. I managed to accomplish something similar with by extending some of the base classes of `spring security rest plugin` to modify the login payload and authentication and exposed a `token/validate` as a REST endpoint. I put up this as an independent authentication service that uses the `/api/login` API for token generation in tandem with the `/token/validate` to accomplish some kind of validation on token. Not a full blown Oauth scenario but serves the purpose of authentication between consumer and provider services.